# Define custom validator by ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can define custom validator that permits first name or last name to be null but not both

My Profile class:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user

     validates :first_name, allow_nil: true
     validates :last_name, allow_nil: true

     validate :first_xor_last


    def first_xor_last
     if (first_name.nil? and last_name.nil?)
        errors[:base] << ("Specify a first or a last.")
      end
    end
```

I tries create by self first_xor_last function but does not work.

I recieve this rspec test:

```
context "rq11" do
       context "Validators:" do
         it "does not allow a User without a username" do
           expect(User.new(:username=> "")).to_not be_valid
         end
         it "does not allow a Profile with a null first and last name" do
           profile = Profile.new(:first_name=>nil, :last_name=>nil, :gender=>"male")
           expect(Profile.new(:first_name=>nil, :last_name=>nil, :gender=>"male")).to_not be_valid
         end
         it "does not allow a Profile with a gender other than male or female " do
           expect(Profile.new(:first_name=>"first", :last_name=>"last", :gender=>"neutral")).to_not be_valid
         end
         it "does not allow a boy named Sue" do
           expect(Profile.new(:first_name=>"Sue", :last_name=>"last", :gender=>"male")).to_not be_valid
         end
       end
     end
```

I should pass it.

Thanks, Michael.

Comment: Unrelated, but I read your method name as meaning you can have a first name or last name but not both.

Comment: ok, thanks I will fix it.

Comment: First thing. The `allow_nil: true` is going against those tests. You should no be allowing them nil. Secondly, You can use the rails `presence: true` instead.

Comment: lcguida, Thanks, it's work!!!!

Comment: If you solved your problem, choose an answer as the correct one =)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `allow_nill` is not a valid validator. You should be using [`presence`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence) or [`absence`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#absence).

Unless you really need a custom message for both fields at the same time, there's no need to use a custom validator, simply do like this:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates :first_name, :last_name, presence: true

end
```

If you want to allow either one, you can use [conditional validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation):

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates :first_name, presence: true, unless: "last_name.present?"
  validates :last_name, presence: true, unless: "first_name.present?"

end
```

Comment: How does this handle the either condition? To my understanding, if `first_name` or `last_name` are missing, an error will show. The specs here stipulate that `first_name` or `last_name` *can* be missing so long as at least one is present.

Comment: it "does not allow a Profile with a null first and last name". From where are you taking that the specs are telling that either one can be missing?

Comment: "that permits first name or last name to be null but not both" - so you can have first_name + no last name, or last_name + no first name. This answer means you *have* to have both, which does not solve the problem.

Comment: Ok, agreed. That is wirtten. But also is written that he wants to make the supplied spec to pass, and those specs says otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
errors[:base] << ("Specify a first or a last.")
```

do

```
errors.add(:base, "Specify a first or a last.")
```

EDIT:

The error message you get is not caused by your custom validation, but by two other validations, which seems not needed, just get rid of those two lines:

```
 validates :first_name, allow_nil: true
 validates :last_name, allow_nil: true
```

Comment: Any feedback? Errors? Messages?

Comment: Profile.all
ArgumentError: You need to supply at least one validation
 from /home/mic3ael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activemodel-4.2.3/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:109:in `validates'
 from /home/mic3ael/Study/ruby/todolists/app/models/profile.rb:4:in `<class:Profile>'
 from /home/mic3ael/Study/ruby/todolists/app/models/profile.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
Maybe this help

Comment: @MichaelHorojanski - Updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validate :presence_of_first_or_last_name

  def presence_of_first_or_last_name
    if (first_name.blank? and last_name.blank?)
      errors[:base] << ("Specify a first or a last.")
    end
  end
end
```

You can lose the two `validates :first_name, allow_nil: true` validations since they do absolutely nothing.

Instead of `.nil?` you might want to use the ActiveSupport method `.blank?` which checks not just for nil but also if the value is an empty string `""` or consists of only whitespaces.

Also as David Newton pointed out XOR is eXclusive OR which would be first_name or last_name but not both. I try to name validators according to the general scheme of `ActiveModel::Validations` - a descriptive name which tells what kind of validation is performed.

Comment: "*also if the value is an empty string*" or [consists of whitespace only](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb#L100).